# Why heroku command: "heroku keys:add" is not working on my machine?

Tags: heroku, web-hosting

I have existing app working on 100% on my localhost and now i want to host it with heroku. After successful login im trying the following command:

**heroku keys:add**

And then it asks me this question:

**Could not find an existing SSH key at ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
? Would you like to generate a new one? (Y/n)**

By clicking **Y** it throws the following exception:

```
Error: spawn ssh-keygen ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1034:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Im not familiar with Heroku and not sure why this error is displayed ?